# ASP.net Wizard Control triggering Page_Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

I am writing a page to collect user information (name, address, credit card info, etc.) for checkout.  The page has an ASP.net Wizard control and assumes that the user is logged in to their website user account.  The Page_Load() contains the following code:

```
        // Get the user
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        // Get the user's profile
        ProfileCommon Profile = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(user.UserName);

        FirstName.Text = Profile.FirstName;
        LastName.Text = Profile.LastName;
        OrganizationName.Text = Profile.OrganizationName;
        Address1.Text = Profile.Address1;
        Address2.Text = Profile.Address2;
        City.Text = Profile.City;
        State.Text = Profile.State;
        ZipCode.Text = Profile.ZipCode;
        Country.Text = Profile.Country;
        Telephone.Text = Profile.Telephone;
        Fax.Text = Profile.Fax;
        Email.Text = user.Email;
```

This successfully loads the user's information into the first step of the wizard.  However, if a user changes the text in any of the textboxes and clicks on Next to go to the next step, and then clicks Previous to go back to the first step, then the page reloads the user's information from Page_Load().  What's a good way to prevent this behavior and retain the changed text in these textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using ISpostback ? if (!IsPostBack) { //page load code goes here }

Answer (score 0):

Check for IsPostBack. This is the way Web Forms works. Every hit calls Page_Load()